# Client can't install IPA because he doesn't have provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, adhoc

Today i finished working on a new game and like usual i export an IPA signed with an AdHoc profile and send it to my client to test the game. but strangely he wasn't able to install it (stacked in "installing" in iTunes) and i believe that this is happening because he doesn't have the Profiles installed in his device (he doesn't see it in settings->general->profiles)

I think the reason why i have the profiles is because i installed the game through xCode.

So am wondering if there is a way around this ? knowing that this is the first time it happens, i was working with this client for the past 9 months and we always worked with this way (adHoc ipa) he never had to install the profiles manually before, all he had to do is to add his Device when creating the profiles, which he did.

Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: You may want to check if your provisioning profile and/or distribution certificate has not expired.

Comment: actually we had that problem yesterday, the certificate was expired but we are using new ones now that expires in 2016. thank you